# CSS: Howto Create Tab Foot?

Tags: css, photoshop, rounded-corners

With most modern browsers is easy to create rounded corners in CSS, so I was wondering if its posible to create a rounded corner that bend outwards or if I still need to fire up PhotoShop for creating such an effect.

The bottom foot in "**See tab**" from the picture below demonstrates what I am trying to do with CSS:

[image]

**note**: I am unsure if *foot* is the correct word for this (which have made googling it hard) so if anyone knows the real (or better) term then please let me know and I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Google is not a verb ;-)

Comment: ^^ that's just me being cheeky.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: [Oops. Pedantry fail.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/google)

Comment: [Use the trademark only as an adjective, never as a noun or verb, and never in the plural or possessive form.](http://www.google.com/permissions/guidelines.html)

Comment: interesting read: http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2006/07/7198.ars

Comment: Interesting, yes - but irrelevant: it's clearly a commonly used verb. I don't think you'll convince anyone that it isn't a verb - [10,200,000 results](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22googling%22) do not [lie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_%28verb%29). :D

Answer (score 1):

Chop that problem up into segments so that the illustration would have a blue shape with one rounded corner on top of a white background, next to the "See" tab, and so on.  By picking the colors carefully, and using shapes that you know you can generate, you can establish a pattern that will work with the tools available.

Notice that you do not have to round all corners on a rectangle.  You can specify, for example, bottom right.

Reference:  http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: To add to this: you can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes in modern browsers to create obligatory elements without messing up your markup. They can be used to display an image, or have a rounded corner where needed.

Comment: perhaps I am missing something obvious but how would you handle the case where the "try" tab is active ?. There is a gloss effect on the bottom half of the inactive tabs and as I see it this effect would carry over to the corners used to fake the foot of the "active tab".

Comment: It requires some fancy footwork, but I would give the tabs before and after the current tab a rounded corner. make the entire `ul` (or whatever element you're using`) have a white background, and only give the gradient to the tabs.